# Jquery - Onclick button trigger all divs within a class

Tags: jquery, html, onclick

I am new to Jquery so please pardon me if I am asking a simple question but I need some help.

In my HTML markup, I have 3 divisions with id from test1 to test3 and a button.

```
<input type="button" id="button_click" value="ok" />
<div class="supercolor" style="width:100px;">
  <div class="colordiv" id="test1" >&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="colordiv" id="test2" >&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="colordiv" id="test3">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

What I want to do is on button click, I want to iterate through all divs in the 'supercolor' class to change the div's css background to red.

Code I have now

```
$('#button_click').click(function(){
   $('div.supercolor').each(function() {
   $(this).css("background-color","red");
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#button_click').click(function() {
    $('.supercolor > div').css('background-color', '#f00');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div.supercolor div').css('background-color', 'red');
```

Is probably what you need.

Comment: I read the question as meaning all divs *with* the `supercolor` class.

Answer (score 1):

actually if they're going to be the same color then you can just do as what minitech suggested. but just for completeness sake.

you just missed out the div in your .each.

```
$('#button_click').click(function(){
   $('div.supercolor > div').each(function() {
   $(this).css("background-color","red");
   });
});
```